# Creating a standalone application in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to create a software using Java. I have coded the application with Java Swing and using backend as MySQL server 5.05.

How can I create an application that can be installed on Windows, and run like other software?

Comment: Net beans creates an executable .jar file every time you re-compile / execute.

Comment: You OK with a jar?  That's about as close to a native-like "application" as you're gonna get without some tool to bundle a JRE and Java classes together into an exe.

Comment: please elaborate your question. Do you want to make executable installer for your application ?

Comment: java requires the JVM to run, so if you want a standalone, the client will either have to install the JVM on their own, or have it included with the installer

Answer (score 0):

Compile it as a JAR and run it in the Windows JRE.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that there *is* a JRE on the user's system.  Windows hasn't come with one for like a decade now, so unless the user's installed one, you're gonna have a problem.

Comment: yes, i was assuming he had a jre since he must have had the jdk to compile it.